# Filtering stderr of subprocess captures empty bytes

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, pipe, command-line-interface

I am calling a very noisy CLI command and want to filter the output, presumably stderr. The CLI binary’s output is shapped like python logging, INFO:… or WARNING:…. When run in a shell, the CLI command first has a few "setup" logs, and after a few seconds the actual logs of several dozen per second start.

I've attempted to PIPE the stderr, and to be sure also the stdout, of the process like this:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while process.stderr:
        line = process.stderr.readline()
        print("STDERR", line)

    while process.stdout:
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        print("STDOUT", line)
```

This works and the STDERR prints appear for the first bits of the CLI command’s execution. However, when I get to the part after a few seconds the output from my STDERR prints is only `b''` — possibly in the same frequency as the normal shell call would output additional logs. I've also tried `read()` instead of `readline()` but to no avail. ("STDOUT" never gets called, btw)

Somehow the output that gets logged on a regular shell call is different or too frequent(?) or incomplete(?) for the PIPE to send it through and read and print it properly.

What could I do to debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to replace those while loops with:

```
for line in iter(process.stderr.readline, b''):
    print("STDERR", line)
```

This would at least deal with the fact that `process.stderr` will never become falsy even when there is nothing to read.

Comment: Thanks. I've done some more digging and it seems somehow whenever I am directing that particular CLI call to PIPE python just freezes up. The previous traces worked and were from another CLI call, but this particular command seems to output something that will break the PIPE'ing.